# How to enable overlay inside of crio containers?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-runner

For Gitlab ci/cd I have the following infrastructure:
There is a Gitlab instance, which is connected to a kubernetes cluster(crio engine),
via a [gitlab kubernetes runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/kubernetes.html).

When there is a commit, the runner picks up the job and runs it in a kubernetes pod.
The first task for each project is to build a container and push it to a container registry, for later use.

The problem I have, is that when `buildah bud ...` runs inside of a kubernetes pod,
it fails mounting an overlay filesystem.

How can I enable mounting overlay filesystems inside of crio containers?

This is the output I have for `buildah bud`:

```
...
Copying blob sha256:9928ff0f1741a74ebd8f82bf56322a0169b9901883323cd810d80e8d3af7f51b
Copying config sha256:c5a6c2ac7afd5f1f541d654e59debec00498486ba2c3e2cd38cff05f703d8a4d
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
time="2023-06-06T10:24:49Z" level=error msg="error unmounting /var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/75c69d9bd322e8ac07ce754d3f0e68b01b6d082f9701116e1864ce2e8c63a906/merged: invalid argument"
error mounting new container: error mounting build container "8514760fdd9c656efafdefb602d464771bcc0762efc6b29d3ad57e7d0ab067bd": error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/75c69d9bd322e8ac07ce754d3f0e68b01b6d082f9701116e1864ce2e8c63a906/merged, mount_data="nodev,fsync=0,lowerdir=/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/l/FWXYQPACKGWNR2OQEH25EZPILD:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/l/MAGCHXOJAEEM77SV4KGFRTBSQL:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/l/AWTORVTBH6UYQ6TDZEFJ4RITXL:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/l/2ECERDL4UK7GOKTU4V5OSEED44:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/l/DFU4RMA5FXX5KRJHFTUTTECUPC:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/l/BKMFQ7S3D65ATHGKAHDLC7CKHX:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/l/2JV3GRA5WEL6BJEX7ADMHE2ICT:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/l/QYTJ4UH5GA2DZR5DCSRJWLIHVQ,upperdir=/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/75c69d9bd322e8ac07ce754d3f0e68b01b6d082f9701116e1864ce2e8c63a906/diff,workdir=/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/75c69d9bd322e8ac07ce754d3f0e68b01b6d082f9701116e1864ce2e8c63a906/work,volatile": using mount program /usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs: fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
fuse-overlayfs: cannot mount: No such file or directory
: exit status 1
time="2023-06-06T10:24:49Z" level=error msg="exit status 125"
building failed with exit code 125
```